# matplotlib colorbar for scatter

Tags: python, colors, matplotlib

I'm working with data that has the data has 3 plotting parameters: x,y,c. How do you create a custom color value for a scatter plot?

Extending this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925806/fixing-color-in-scatter-plots-in-matplotlib) I'm trying to do:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cm = matplotlib.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
colors=[cm(1.*i/20) for i in range(20)]
xy = range(20)
plt.subplot(111)
colorlist=[colors[x/2] for x in xy] #actually some other non-linear relationship
plt.scatter(xy, xy, c=colorlist, s=35, vmin=0, vmax=20)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

but the result is `TypeError: You must first set_array for mappable`

Answer (score 256, accepted):

From the matplotlib docs on scatter [1](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter):

> cmap is only used if c is an array of floats

So colorlist needs to be a list of floats rather than a list of tuples as you have it now.
plt.colorbar() wants a mappable object, like the CircleCollection that plt.scatter() returns.
vmin and vmax can then control the limits of your colorbar.  Things outside vmin/vmax get the colors of the endpoints.

How does this work for you?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
xy = range(20)
z = xy
sc = plt.scatter(xy, xy, c=z, vmin=0, vmax=20, s=35, cmap=cm)
plt.colorbar(sc)
plt.show()
```

[image: Image Example]

Comment: I tried it and got `'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'colorbar'`. I've done `ax.colorbar()` ... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This example does not provide a clear application when using matplotlib OOP interface: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/agg_oo_sgskip.html

Answer (score 40):

Here is [the OOP way](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html) of adding a colorbar:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.scatter(x, y, c=c)
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
```

Comment: When I do this, I end up with the plot completely rescale so that all the points are within a sliver of the plot on the far right, and the colorbar is a very thin line across the bottom.

Comment: The right answer, directly using `plt` to plot colorbar is not a recommended way I think. Yours is a commended way.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to scatter by two variables and color by the third, [Altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/) can be a great choice.

#### Creating the dataset

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(40*np.random.randn(10, 3), columns=['A', 'B','C'])
```

Altair plot

```
from altair import *
Chart(df).mark_circle().encode(x='A',y='B', color='C').configure_cell(width=200, height=150)
```

#### Plot

[image]