# Matplotlib scatter intensity

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, scatter-plot, matplotlib-basemap

I have created a global contour for d18O with a specified range and colorbar.

```
lon = np.arange(-180.0,180.0,1)
lat = np.arange(-90.0,90.0,1)
m1 = Basemap(projection='mill',llcrnrlat=-90,urcrnrlat=90,
             llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,resolution='c')
x,y = m1(*np.meshgrid(lon, lat))
colors=[-5.6,-4.4,-3.6,-3.2,-2.8,-2.4,-2.0,-1.7,-1.4,-1.1,-.8,-.5,
        -.2,.2,.4,.6,.8,1.0,1.3,1.6,2.0,2.4,2.8]

m1.contourf(x, y, d18o_fal,colors) #d18o_fal is a 360x180 matrix of d18O values.
m1.drawcoastlines()
m1.fillcontinents()
m1.drawmapboundary()
plt.title(Fall+' Calculated Surface $\delta^{18}$O Seawater')
cbar = plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal', extend='both')
cbar.ax.set_xlabel('O18/O16 permilli')
plt.show()
```

I am trying to plot a scatterplot of the arctic with the color intensity equal to the intensity of d18O (Figure a). The points are from long, lat, and d18o.

Much like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kozx.jpg
(Figure 1A)

Sorry I can't post pictures yet!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely clear on where you get the "intensity of d18O" but basically you need to call `scatter()` with the `c` parameter set to a list of intensity (same size as the number of points), and map the color using a cmap.

see the documentation for [scatter](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter)

and tons of examples on SO: [matplotlib colorbar for scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063876/matplotlib-colorbar-for-scatter)