# How do I use seaborn's lmplot to show a colobar for hue, instead of exact values?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to get my seaborn plot to look something like this:
[image]

If I use lmplot with the z-axis for the hue, I get this:
[image]

The lmplot in the picture is basically what I want, but I need the colorbar on the right side instead of the actual values.

I tried to do this with a heatmap, but the data plot was worse that way due to the large gaps between samples.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `plt.scatter`. The `hue` parameter in `lmplot` only accepts categorical variables.

Comment: Link to a way to do this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063876/matplotlib-colorbar-for-scatter).