# Display colorbar with a plot on mollweide projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I try to do a scatterplot of `lll` and `bbb` variables with `amplitudes` as color with a mollweide projection with a colorbar.

If I do

```
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
lll=N.random.uniform(-180,180,10000)
bbb=N.random.uniform(-90,90,10000)
amp=N.random.uniform(0,1,10000)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="mollweide")
ax.scatter(N.array(lll)*N.pi/180., N.array(bbb)*N.pi/180., c=amp)

ax.grid(True)
```

I get the plot I want but without the colorbar. If I add a line with `ax.colorbar()` or `plt.colorbar()` it don't work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [matplotlib colorbar for scatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063876/matplotlib-colorbar-for-scatter)

Comment: Thanks, I edit to get a minimal working code.

Its not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063876/matplotlib-colorbar-for-scatter , I use mollweide projection

Comment: Did you try the solution in the duplicate? For me it produces a colorbar

Comment: yes, I a add plt.colorbar(ax), I get AttributeError: 'MollweideAxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return the value from `ax.scatter`, then pass that as an argument into  `plt.colorbar` (*not* the axes itself):

```
lll=np.random.uniform(0,360,10000)
bbb=np.random.uniform(-90,90,10000)
amplitudes=np.random.uniform(0,1,10000)

l_axis_name ='latitude l (deg)'
b_axis_name = 'longitude b (deg)'

for i in range(len(lll)):
    if lll[i]>180:
        lll[i] -= 360
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="mollweide")
ax.grid(True)

sc = ax.scatter(np.array(lll)*np.pi/180., np.array(bbb)*np.pi/180., c=amplitudes)
plt.colorbar(sc)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks you very much