# How to change number of rows in legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create a scatter plot, but the auto-created legend is out from range (0...100). [120% label in legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeVuL.jpg).

```py
sns.scatterplot(data=df1,x='x',y='y',hue='percent',ax=ax1)
```

I tried to pass list of labels:

```py
plt.legend(labels=[0.0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1.0])
```

But it still doesn't look good:

[image: link]

Comment: Dataset has a lot of unique percent value, so I can't use this parameter: 
   legend : "full"

Comment: Since you seem to be new to Stack Overflow, you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It'd be good to see which values does the `percent` feature have. Are you sure its data is correct?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you interested in something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063876/matplotlib-colorbar-for-scatter

Comment: @89f3a1c, I'm sure. Data is correct - [link](https://imgur.com/a/mLD2K8e)

Comment: Wow, @Zaya, I didn't know about colorbar :D
Graph looks much better with it, than that legend I tried to do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Zaya, Post your comment as answer, I' ll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib's colorbar is a great way to depict a range of values on a scatterplot. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063876/matplotlib-colorbar-for-scatter).