# Matplotlib coloured scatter legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a scatter graph using matplot lib of one line where the points are coloured according to a third value. I need to add a legend to explain what the colours mean. For example a white point means '0' and a red point means '5'. 
This seems like a really obvious thing to do but I cannot find any information anywhere online about how to do it.

Comment: See: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/6065493/11743318](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6065493/11743318) for a scatter plot with a colorbar

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was aware of colorbar before but it isn't suitable here because the categories are discrete.

Comment: This might help: [https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#discrete-intervals-colorbar](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#discrete-intervals-colorbar)