# matplotlib imshow how to plot points instead of image?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is the code:

```
plots=imshow(Z,extent=extent,origin,cmap=cmap,aspect='auto',vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax)
plots.plot(Response,component,vrange)
```

It plots an image based on data list Z, how can I let it print data points instead of an image?

Looks like needs to change to scatter(x, y,...) to plot data points, how difficult it is to change array Z to x, y?

Answer (score 5):

As @jdj081 said, you want to produce a scatter plot.

```
import os.path

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# get an image from the sample data directory
fname = os.path.join(matplotlib.get_data_path(), 'sample_data', 'lena.png')
im = plt.imread(fname)

# Reduce the data by a factor of 4 (so that we can see the points)
im = im[::4, ::4]

# generate coordinates for the image. Note that the image is "top down", so the y coordinate goes from high to low.
ys, xs = np.mgrid[im.shape[0]:0:-1, 0:im.shape[1]]

# Scatter plots take 1d arrays of xs and ys, and the colour takes a 2d array,
# with the second dimension being RGB
plt.scatter(xs.flatten(), ys.flatten(), s=4,
            c=im.flatten().reshape(-1, 3), edgecolor='face')
plt.show()
```

[image: scatter plot of lena]

Comment: Yes. I want scatter points. Z includes data like this z [[ 1.09415996  1.43587005  0.89219701 ..., -1.00144994  0.14369801
   1.18596005]
 [ 1.09415996  1.43587005  0.89219701 ..., -1.00144994  0.14369801
   1.18596005]
 ..., 
 [-0.2372447   0.69860512  0.04342676 ..., -0.08253406 -0.51178968
  -0.35968387]
 [-0.27594933  0.54936659  0.32261935 ..., -0.13794966 -0.53104192
  -0.35142872]] After input to imshow(z,...), it turns out to be a picture, not different points. Does this imshow() interpolate the data into a picture?

Comment: Yes. See http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html (for interpolation schemes: http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html#array-interpolation-schemes)

Comment: Any example how to change the array Z into array x, y, so I can use it in scatter()? Thanks

Comment: x and y are the coordinates of Z. So simply doing ``ys, xs = np.mgrid[im.shape[0]:0:-1, 0:im.shape[1]]`` is what you are after isn't it?

Comment: Looks like change to scatter() not work, it want x, y must be same size, but you know my imshow() picture doesn't have same size. Just wondering why can't plot points using imshow() directly?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide much information to go on, but it sounds like you really want to create a scatter plot.

There are many options here depending on what you are plotting and what you want to see, but I have found the following helpful:

[Fixing color in scatter plots in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925806/fixing-color-in-scatter-plots-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Z is an array like this z [[ 1.09415996 1.43587005 0.89219701 ..., -1.00144994 0.14369801 1.18596005] [ 1.09415996 1.43587005 0.89219701 ..., -1.00144994 0.14369801 1.18596005]]. Can I create scatter plot using imshow()?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pylab
pylab.figure(1)
pylab.plot([1,2,3,4],[1,7,3,5]) # draw on figure one
pylab.show() # show figure on screen
```